# Reactivecocoa 4 SignalProducer

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I have 2 signal producers
1. Get user Info from Network
2. get User Info from NSUserDefaults if it exist

I only want to call Network SignalProducer If I don't have value in NSUserDefaults. I am using If condition right now but Is there a way to chain these 2 signals ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your second producer sends an error if the user doesn't exist:

```
defaultsUserInfoProducer.flatMapError { _ in networkProducer}
```